# How to dynamically add an attribute to JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON array

```
{"nodes":[
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-start","content":"Start"},
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-1","content":"Ironing"},
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-end""content":"End"}
         ],

"connections":[
        {"start":"node-start","end":"node-1"},
        {"start":"node-4","end":"node-5"}
              ]
}
```

I need to dynamically add "top" attribute to each element in nodes array so that it may look like this

```
{"nodes":[
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"top":3403.252685546875,"id":"node-start","content":"Start"},
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"top":3703.252685546875,"id":"node-1","content":"Ironing"},
        {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"top":3903.252685546875,"id":"node-end""content":"End"}
         ],

"connections":[
        {"start":"node-start","end":"node-1"},
        {"start":"node-4","end":"node-5"}
              ]
```

Comment: iterate and apply.

Comment: Is the JSON parsed? Where are those new `top` numbers coming from? Are they random numbers? What have you tried? There's not enough info here to give a decent answer.

Comment: @Squint yes json is parsed. new top is coming from the offset of a control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` on `obj.nodes` and add object property

```js
var obj = {"nodes":[{"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-start","content":"Start"},{"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-1","content":"Ironing"},{"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-end","content":"End"}],"connections":[{"start":"node-start","end":"node-1"},{"start":"node-4","end":"node-5"}]}

obj.nodes.forEach((e) => {
  e.top = 3403.252685546875;
});

console.log(obj)
```

Update: First you need to turn your json string to object with `JSON.parse(yourjson)` if you didn't.

Comment: This will work if the JSON is already parsed and if the OP wanted to add the same number to each object. The question doesn't indicate either of those.

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse($("#hdnchartJSON").val());
             var i = 100;
             obj.nodes.forEach((e) => {
                 e.top = $("#Label2").offset().top + i;
                 i = i + 100;
             });

Solved

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj={"nodes":[
       {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-start","content":"Start"},
       {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-1","content":"Ironing"},
       {"type":"simple-node","left":500,"id":"node-end""content":"End"}
     ]};
      var top_array=[2495,4985,3467];
      for(i=0;i<obj.nodes.length;i++){
          obj.nodes[i].top=top_array[i];
       }
```

In case you need to copy the keys from an array